# How to prevent a notification from being sent to Wear?

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

i'm building an ongoing notification in my app.

I didn't found how to prevent it from being sent to wear.

i thought that ongoing notification were not sent but my notification is sent anymay. (i have used  mBuilder.setOngoing(true);)

Anybody has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Notification.Builder class you have a "[setLocalOnly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean))" method that allows you to configure this.